# Postgresql on linux ami

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm a newbie to aws and postgresql
I've launch an instance with quick wizard of linux ami 2013.03.01
It says that the instance include a repository access to postgresql - I thought that means that it's already installed on the machine, and since i could not locate it I decided to install postgresql on my own following [this great guide](http://www.codingsteps.com/installing-and-configuring-postgresql-in-amazon-linux-ami/)
in step 10:PostGIS installation
when executing this command

```
./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config --with-raster
```

i get the following warnings:

```
configure: WARNING: ImageMagick does not seem to be installed. Documentation cannot be built
configure: WARNING: dblatex is not installed so PDF documentation cannot be built
configure: WARNING: could not locate Docbook stylesheets required to build the documentation
configure: WARNING: could not locate CUnit required for unit tests
```

and the command ends with the following error:

```
configure: error: could not find geos-config within the current path. You may need to try re-running configure with a --with-geosconfig parameter.
```

i've tried this command

```
./configure --with-geosconfig=/usr/local/bin/geos-config
```

I get the same warnings as above and the following error
configure: error: could not find pg_config within the current path. You may need to try re-running configure with a --with-pgconfig parameter.
can some one help me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You get some warnings about missing software. Why don't you install those?

```
yum install imagemagick
```

Etc for the other missing packages...

The configure problem, see http://postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/Why-can-t-PostGIS-configure-find-libgeos-c-td3552982.html and the reply

> I might be outdated here, but the message seems clearly stating you're supposed to pass it a directory, not a file. Lame, but most likely that's your problem.
>
> Try using: --with-geosconfig=/usr/local/bin

Comment: I tried the part with the directory, didn't work, I've installed the ImageMagic but I still get the other warnings about dblatex, Docbook and CUnit any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile PostgreSQL and install it manually! Just use the existing packaged version:

```
sudo yum -y install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
sudo service postgresql initdb
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --levels 235 postgresql on
sudo service postgresql start
```

... [per the first Google hit for "amazon linux install postgresql"](https://gist.github.com/dstroot/2920991).

That said, [Amazon Linux's PostgreSQL packaging is bad bordering on incompetent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28245/7788), and it should be avoided in favour of a distro that has [properly maintained](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) PostgreSQL packages like Ubuntu, Debian, or Fedora/RHEL.